# Como calcular a MODA com valor bimodal em um data.frame no R?

Tags: r, matemática, data.frame

Preciso calcular a MODA dos valores em linha em um data.frame. Como no `R` não existe uma função já definida para MODA, usei uma função customizada:

```
moda = function(x) {
  z = table(as.vector(x))
  names(z)[z == max(z)]
}

teste1 = moda(c(1,2,3,4,5,5,5))

print(teste1)
[1] 5
```

A função `moda` funciona muito bem por sinal, agora vamos para um outro caso:

```
teste2 = moda(c(1,1,1,2,3,4,5,5,5))

    print(teste2)
    [1] "1" "5"
```

No teste2, o vetor possui valor bimodal e a função `moda` exibe dois valores. Agora vamos para o terceiro caso usando um data.frame:

```
print(DADOS)

 Linha  A   B   C   D   E
 L1     4   3   2   1   4
 L2     1   11  1   1   1
 L3     0   1   2   2   4
 L4     2   0   0   8   0
```

Neste caso vou ter que criar mais uma coluna com valores de cada linha calculados pela MODA:

```
DADOS = DADOS %>%
rowwise() %>%
mutate(MODA = moda(c(A,B,C,D,E)))

print(DADOS)

 Linha  A   B   C   D   E  MODA
 L1     4   3   2   1   4   4
 L2     1   11  1   1   1   1
 L3     0   1   2   2   4   2
 L4     2   0   0   8   0   0
```

Funcionou perfeitamente, porém chegamos na "situação problema". Neste último caso vou usar um data.frame diferente:

```
print(DADOS_2)

Linha  A   B   C   D   E
L1     4   3   2   2   4
L2     1   11  1   1   1
L3     0   1   2   3   4
L4     2   0   0   8   0
```

Como no caso anterior vou ter que criar mais uma coluna com valores de cada linha calculados pela MODA:

```
DADOS_2 = DADOS_2 %>%
rowwise() %>%
mutate(MODA = moda(c(A,B,C,D,E)))

print(DADOS_2)

Error: Column `MODA` must be length 1 (the group size), not 2
```

O `R` me exibe a mensagem de erro, porque na base `DADOS_2` a linha `L1` traz um exemplo claro de valor bimodal L1=(**4**,3,**2**,**2**,**4**). E por se tratar de um valor bimodal, o `R` não consegue atribuir dois valores em uma coluna só.

O que devo fazer nesse caso? Como posso calcular a MODA em linha com valor bimodal em um data.frame?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode solucionar este problema com `tidyverse`. Antes, crio um exemplo reprodutível:

```
data <- data.frame(
  a = c(1, 2, 2, 7, 3), 
  b = c(2, 2, 1, 1, 2), 
  d = c(1, 3, 2, 2, 3), 
  e = c(2, 3, 1, 2, 2)
)
```

Vou usar a função que você criou:

```
moda = function(x) {
  z = table(as.vector(x))
  names(z)[z == max(z)]
}
```

Segue o código:

```
library(tidyverse)

res <- data %>% 
  mutate(my_mode_1 = pmap(., lift_vd(moda))) %>% 
  mutate_if(is.list, as.character) %>% 
  mutate(my_mode_2 = str_remove_all(string = my_mode_1, pattern = '[(),c"]')) %>% 
  separate(col = my_mode_2, sep = ' ', 
       into = c('mode_1', 'mode_2', 'mode_3'), fill = 'right') %>% 
  mutate_at(c('mode_1', 'mode_2', 'mode_3'), as.numeric) %>% 
  select(- my_mode_1)

res

  a b d e mode_1 mode_2 mode_3
1 1 2 1 2      1      2   <NA>
2 2 2 3 3      2      3   <NA>
3 2 1 2 1      1      2   <NA>
4 7 1 2 2      2     NA   <NA>
5 3 2 3 2      2      3   <NA>
```

Dois pontos:

- Na linha `4` há apenas uma moda. Por isso, em `mode_2`, não existe valor.
- Note que criei, propositalmente, uma coluna adicional. Pois, se existissem 3 modas, a terceira seria ali alocada. Mas, nada te impede de remover esta coluna com um `select`.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, vou testar.

Comment: Giovani usei sua solução com a minha base que possui seis colunas. Mas me mandou uma mensagem de erro: Warning message:Expected 3 pieces.

Comment: Quando diminuiu para três colunas funcionou, mas com 6 colunas eu recebo essa mensagem de erro. No seu código tem como definir os números de colunas que eu quero trabalhar?

Comment: Tente aumentar o número de colunas. Coloque 6 (por exemplo, `mode_1`, `mode_2` até `mode_6`. Faça isso dentro do argumento `into = c()` e em `mutate_at`.

Comment: Por exemplo: tem como eu escolher as colunas (A,C e E) para calcular a MODA?

Comment: É só dar um `select` e escolher estas variáveis no início da análise.

Comment: Uma última coisa Giovani... quando tenho uma amostra exemplo: c(1,2,3,4,5,6) ele considera todos como moda, mas na verdade não existe moda porque nenhum número se repete.

Comment: Então você teria que ajustar a função para resolver este detalhe. Veja que as modas foram criadas com base na função `moda`.